# Raw string to python dictionary (?)

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am creating a dictionary first as a raw string, and then using b = eval(raw string) to define b. This works fine when I cut and paste the raw string into the python console, but when I run my program I get the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Minimum Code Example:

```
def drawBoardData2():
    cells = ''
    cells+=("r\'{")
    for r in range(0,2):
        c = 2
        cc = "light"
        piece = "b"
        player = "A"
        if r != 1:
            comma = ","
        else:
            comma = ""
        cells += ("\"{r}.{c}\":[1,1,\"{color}\",\"{pi}\",\"{pl}\",\"none\"]{cm} ".format(r=r, c=c, color=cc, pi=piece, pl=player, cm=comma))
    cells += ("}\'")
    #print("}\'")
    print(cells)
    b = eval(cells)
    print(b)
    print(type(b)) # result: <class 'str'> instead of <class 'dict'>
    b["1.2"] # result: "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

drawBoardData2()
```

The code gives me `cells` = `r'{"0.2":[1,1,"light","b","A","none"], "1.2":[1,1,"light","b","A","none"] }'`
`print(type(b))` gives me `<class 'str'>` instead of `<class 'dict'>`.
If I cut and paste this into the console in PyCharm, and use the `eval()` command, it gives me a dictionary. Does anyone know why it works in the console, but not when I run the program?

How can I fix this? I've tried `ast` as well, but had the same result:

```
import ast
b = ast.literal_eval(cells)
print(type(b)) # <class 'str'>
# still gives me a string instead of a dictionary
# unless I copy & paste the raw string and use it in the console, then it works fine
```

Maybe I need to use different quote marks, or escape quotes?
I thought using a raw string would solve this.

Comment: Is there a reason that you aren't using `json.loads(cells)`?

Comment: Sorry if i'm drifting from your question, but why are you parsing it yourself and not loading it with `json.loads`?

Answer (score 5):

As written, you could make it work by just changing:

```
b = eval(cells)
```

to:

```
b = eval(eval(cells))
```

or slightly safer/nicer:

```
b = ast.literal_eval(ast.literal_eval(cells))
```

This works because you didn't build a "string representing a `dict`", you built a "string representing a raw string literal representing a `dict`"; with two layers of "string" around it, it needs to be `eval`-ed twice to get the `dict` itself. When you only `eval`ed once, you got the string represented by the raw string literal you `eval`-ed, but you stopped short of converting that to a `dict`.

That said, you seem to be a little confused on the value of raw strings; building a string containing the definition of a raw string won't do much for you, since the values you're inserting won't have backslash escapes in them in the first place (and when they have backslashes, they're probably not meant to be escapes). So a better solution is to just avoid the raw string wrapping, so you build a string representing a `dict`, not a string representing a string representing a `dict`. The change is just changing:

```
cells = ''
cells+=("r\'{")
...
cells += ("}\'")
```

to:

```
cells = "{"
...
cells += "}"
```

(removing a bunch of kruft you didn't need in the bargain)

This gets you back to only needing one level of `eval`/`ast.literal_eval`.

That said, it seems rather silly to use `eval`/`ast.literal_eval` at all. Building the actual `dict` directly seems the sane solution here:

```
import json

def drawBoardData2():
    cells = {}
    for r in range(0,2):
        cells[f'{r}.2'] = [1, 1, "light", "b", "A", "none"]
    print(cells)
    print(json.dumps(cells))

drawBoardData2()
```

where `json.dumps` lets you convert it to a string form that consistently uses double-quotes, assuming that's a design requirement.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5NCsIwEIX3PcXQTRsoRetOcKF4i9JFNEkbSSdhGhEpPXtMQxFxGB7z8z547u0Hi4cQ9OgseXhMFrNMSAWC@OtiOYkr97wp2TGDWHdpzAQnmJe0KktAoBGIYy/LXdVsvq@3VcVMS90UXaTafQWxc6P7wedxuK1yXgUtyrxLrCONvkw0@zms0WrxHN20/VgM@hcyhA8)

Comment: Thanks, regarding your last `json.dumps` solution, how would this look if I wanted "light", "b", and "A" to be variables? I'm not sure how to use `{variable 1}`, `{variable 2}`, and where to put the .format( ... )

Comment: @WesTomer: You'd just replace `"light"` with the name of a variable (e.g. `cc` in your original code). You're not doing any formatting anymore (except to make the keys in `cells`, done with an f-string). It's just making normal `list`s and `dict`s, and at the very end, if you need it in JSON legal string format (with strings quoted with `"`), you convert the true `dict` to its JSON-equivalent `str`.